# How do I populate a single external table from multiple different local tables without overwriting?

Tags: append, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have 2 Access DB's: One to be used on 50 different laptops to store data locally and then one DB to store all the aggregated data from these 50 laptops.

**Procedure:**

Users will be periodically going to each of these 50 laptops and entering data in via a form. All forms are the same. Heck, the entire DB is the same thing for all 50 laptops.

I need to collect all their data into one *external* table in DB #2. How do I accomplish this? Ideally, I'd like to append to the external table as soon as the user successfully submits data (real-time data is cool).

Answer (score 0):

Add a StationId or similar to the external table.

Assign each laptop a unique StationId.

Whenever you append data from a specific laptop, apply the StationId of the laptop.